# cannot execute binary file: Exec format error - Ubuntu 16.04 + Make + GCC

Tags: compiling, gcc, make, makefile

I am aware that other people had similar issues but mine seem to be unique as I am not making obvious mistakes. I have reviewed other questions and putting all required details below.

When I am trying to execute a binary (swetest.o) which I compiled using make I am getting below error

```
bash: ./swetest.o: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Here is my system information

```
uname -a
Linux vXXXXXX 4.4.0-141-generic #167-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 5 10:40:15 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Here is my file information

```
file swetest.o
swetest.o: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
```

Here is my compiler info

```
gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Here is the "Makefile"

```
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -fPIC     # for Linux and other gcc systems
OP=$(CFLAGS)  
CC=gcc  #for Linux

# compilation rule for general cases
.o :
    $(CC) $(OP) -o $@ $? -lm
.c.o:
    $(CC) -c $(OP) $<     

SWEOBJ = swedate.o swehouse.o swejpl.o swemmoon.o swemplan.o swepcalc.o sweph.o\
    swepdate.o swephlib.o swecl.o swehel.o

swetest: swetest.o libswe.a
    $(CC) $(OP) -o swetest swetest.o -L. -lswe -lm -ldl

swemini: swemini.o libswe.a
    $(CC) $(OP) -o swemini swemini.o -L. -lswe -lm

# create an archive and a dynamic link libary for SwissEph
# a user of this library will inlcude swephexp.h  and link with -lswe

libswe.a: $(SWEOBJ)
    ar r libswe.a   $(SWEOBJ)

libswe.so: $(SWEOBJ)
    $(CC) -shared -o libswe.so $(SWEOBJ)

clean:
    rm -f *.o swetest libswe*

###
swecl.o: swejpl.h sweodef.h swephexp.h swedll.h sweph.h swephlib.h
sweclips.o: sweodef.h swephexp.h swedll.h
swedate.o: swephexp.h sweodef.h swedll.h
swehel.o: swephexp.h sweodef.h swedll.h
swehouse.o: swephexp.h sweodef.h swedll.h swephlib.h swehouse.h
swejpl.o: swephexp.h sweodef.h swedll.h sweph.h swejpl.h
swemini.o: swephexp.h sweodef.h swedll.h
swemmoon.o: swephexp.h sweodef.h swedll.h sweph.h swephlib.h
swemplan.o: swephexp.h sweodef.h swedll.h sweph.h swephlib.h swemptab.h
swepcalc.o: swepcalc.h swephexp.h sweodef.h swedll.h
sweph.o: swejpl.h sweodef.h swephexp.h swedll.h sweph.h swephlib.h
swephlib.o: swephexp.h sweodef.h swedll.h sweph.h swephlib.h
swetest.o: swephexp.h sweodef.h swedll.h
```

**Thanks for help!**

Comment: `swetest.o` is the (intermediate) object file; the thing you should be trying to execute is the linked executable `swetest`

Comment: Thanks...It worked.